# REST V1.0 API depretiation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Since the email from MS pointed me here.

Does the depreciation of all the REST and Discovery services mess up using the managed APIs?

we have some application that access things using the managed APIs. We have some things using DLLs such as Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient, exchange DLLs, and some SharePoint things.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide more detail information.  What is the managed APIS you mean, for EWS or SharePoint?

Comment: We received an email from MS titled "Awareness: REST API and Action Required By Date: Nov 1 2018"